# Playing sound from object URL

Tags: android, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, html5-audio

I use XMLHttpRequest to preload files for a game. If WebAudio isnt supported I fall back to using audio elements.

On Android it works fine in Firefox but sound does not play in chrome. Here's some testing code:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if( window.audio ) window.audio.play();
    console.log( window.audio );
});

window.audio    = null;


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/sounds/shotgun.webm', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        var blob = new Blob( new Array( new Int8Array( xhr.response ) ), { type: 'audio/webm' } );
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL( blob )
        window.audio = new Audio();
        window.audio.src = url;

        console.log( 'sound loaded' );
    }
    };

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send();
```

I suspect this is a Chrome for android issue with the object url...

Anyway I'm looking for a way to play sounds on Chrome for Android using cached data from an XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does in fact appear to be a bug.  I have raised it here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227476 and created a test case for it.  When I get back from vacation I will assign it to the correct team if it has not already been triaged.  I will also update this answer if I find any other work around.

Comment: Did you get any further with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Android phone handy, but I know that in the past you needed to use `window.webkitURL` instead of `window.URL`. Maybe try:

`( window.URL || window.webkitURL ).createObjectURL( blob )`

Comment: nope doesnt work. I also tried to create urls using the file system API, and well no luck.